# Microsoft IE9beta broke my IE install

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

Now I cannot use IE8 or 9, when trying to re-install IE9 from the Microsoft website, the installer tells me I "Have a newer version installed."

I cannot find IE in the Installed Programs section in Control Panel.

How can I revert to IE8 on Windows 7 32-bit home premium?

Thankyou very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

via [Download Squad](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/09/18/how-to-uninstall-internet-explorer-9/)

> Internet Explorer 9 installs as a
>   Windows update. Here's what you need
>   to do to uninstall IE9 on Windows
>   Vista or Windows 7:
>    - Click your Windows button and type `View Updates` in the search box once
>   the results appear, click view
>   installed updates
>
> Don't want to search?
>
> - Press Win+R and paste in the following:  `C:\Windows\explorer.exe
>     shell:::{d450a8a1-9568-45c7-9c0e-b4f9fb4537bd}`
>     then press Enter.
> - Wait for the Uninstall an update screen to load completely scroll
>     through the list until you find
>     Windows Internet Explorer 9
> - Click once to highlight IE9, then click the Uninstall button (or
>     right-click and uninstall) confirm
>     that you want to uninstall (click yes)